# Cmake - Generate shared library with OpenCV inside

Tags: python, c++, opencv, cmake, shared-libraries

I compiled a `.so` file using the following `CmakeList.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.1)
project(phase)
SET(OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS "/usr/local/include/opencv")
include_directories(INCLUDE_DIR include ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
set(OpenCV_LIB_DIR "/usr/local/lib")
link_directories(${OpenCV_LIB_DIR})
aux_source_directory(src SOURCE)
add_library(dct SHARED src/dct.c ${SOURCE})
```

It did not give me any error. The, I wanted to use it in a Python Project:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.ctypeslib as npct
from ctypes import c_int, c_double

_array_1d_floatBase = npct.ndpointer(dtype=np.float32, ndim=1, flags="CONTIGUOUS")

def _from_param(cls, obj):
    if obj is None:
        return obj
    return _array_1d_floatBase.from_param(obj)

array_1d_float = type(
    'DoubleArrayType',
    (_array_1d_floatBase,),
    {'from_param': classmethod(_from_param)}
)
array_1d_double = npct.ndpointer(dtype=np.double, ndim=1, flags="CONTIGUOUS")
libcd = npct.load_library("/home/facu/libdct.so", ".")
libcd.FastCosineTransform.restype = None
libcd.FastCosineTransform.argtypes = [array_1d_float, c_int, c_int, c_int]

def dct_lib(in_array, xsize, ysize, sign):
    libcd.FastCosineTransform(in_array, xsize, ysize, sign)
    return in_array 

in_array = laplacian
print in_array
out_dct = dct_lib(in_array, 512, 512, 1)
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
OSError: /home/facu/libdct.so: undefined symbol: cvGetSeqElem
```

I think I  missing something in my cmake file. What have I to include for generating a `.so` with OpenCV inside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't find the part in your CMakeLists.txt where you actually call something like `target_link_libraries(dct opencv)`. I'm not sure whether there's a lookup routine like `find_package(opencv REQUIRED)` or similar or whether you'd have to build one if you planned to use `find_package`. 
You have to link the library itself somewhere. So far you're only setting the path where the library resides, but not the actual library name to link.

EDIT: Google is your friend. [Here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_gcc_cmake/linux_gcc_cmake.html) you'll find how to link against openCV using CMake.